RabbitMQ Messaging Issue: i can`t send messages between .NET and springboot
I created two queues: one called receive_queue and the other called send_queue. The .NET publisher sends a message to the receive_queue, while the same .NET service consumer listens to the send_queue. However, the consumer receives messages from the .NET producer, not the receive_queue.
I also created a listener in a Spring Boot API that listens to the receive_queue, but it does not receive any messages from the .NET producer. To troubleshoot, I deleted the .NET consumer, but the Spring Boot listener still does not receive anything.
This is the RabbitMQ configuration:
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(producerJackson2MessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
}

this is the serializer configuration
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE); // If needed
        return mapper;
    }
}

this is the receive queue exchange and binding configuration
@Configuration
public class ReceiveRabbitMQConfig {

    public static final String RECEIVE_QUEUE = "receive_queue";
    public static final String RECEIVE_EXCHANGE = "receive_exchange";
    public static final String RECEIVE_ROUTING_KEY = "receive";

    @Bean
    public Queue receiveQueue() {
        return new Queue(RECEIVE_QUEUE, true);
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange receiveExchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(RECEIVE_EXCHANGE);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding receiveBinding() {
        return BindingBuilder
                .bind(receiveQueue())
                .to(receiveExchange())
                .with(RECEIVE_ROUTING_KEY);
    }
}

this is the send queue exchange and binding configuration
@Configuration
public class SendRabbitMQConfig {

    public static final String SEND_QUEUE = "send_queue";
    public static final String SEND_EXCHANGE = "send_exchange";
    public static final String SEND_ROUTING_KEY = "send";

    @Bean
    public Queue sendQueue() {
        return new Queue(SEND_QUEUE, true);
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange sendExchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(SEND_EXCHANGE);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding sendBinding() {
        return BindingBuilder
                .bind(sendQueue())
                .to(sendExchange())
                .with(SEND_ROUTING_KEY);
    }
}

this is the springbootlistner
@Component
public class RabbitMQListener {

    @RabbitListener(queues = "receive_queue")
    public void listen(SimpleMessage message) {
        System.out.println("Received message: " + message.getText());
    }
}

this .NET masstransit configuration
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host("rabbitmq://localhost", h =>
        {
            h.Username("guest");
            h.Password("guest");
        });
        cfg.UseRawJsonDeserializer();
        cfg.UseNewtonsoftJsonSerializer();
      
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("send_queue", e =>
        {
            e.Consumer<SimpleMessageConsumer>();

        });
    });
});
builder.Services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

this the .NET consumer
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MassTransit;

namespace UsersService.Consumers
{
    public class SimpleMessageConsumer : IConsumer<SimpleMessage>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<SimpleMessage> context)
        {
            var message = context.Message;
            Console.WriteLine("message received " + message.Text);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}

this is .NET producer
          SimpleMessage simpleMessage=  new SimpleMessage() { Text = token };
            await bus.Publish(simpleMessage, context =>
            {
                context.SetRoutingKey("receive");

               
            });

message schema in the  services
namespace UsersService
{
    public class SimpleMessage
    {
        public string Text { get; set; } = "token";
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SimpleMessage {
    private String text;
}

Next, I created a Spring Boot producer that sends messages to the receive_queue, and the Spring Boot listener successfully receives the messages. I then changed the Spring Boot listener to listen to the send_queue and updated the .NET producer to send messages to the send_queue. While the Spring Boot listener receives the messages, the properties of the received message are null.
